# Angular 7 -what is mechanism behind creating components with isolated scope with styles in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular 7 - does core library using shadow dom element to handle isolated scope. what is scene behind the creating components in angular 7 and how isolated scope its working ?

can anyone please help me to understand this ?

Comment: Is the question is about the data scope or the style scope?

Comment: @Mukundhan its about how angular internally creating components and attaching to dom

Comment: Understood, interesting indeed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the document of angular, DOM encapsulation is used for component-specific style inject.

This seems to be the key feature like creating a pseudo element and attaching the styles in the name of it.

[MDN-Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)

[Angular-Docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation)

**Update**

Found this in angular's official repo: [style_compiler](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/packages/compiler/src/style_compiler.ts)

need to study deeply though!

Comment: thanks for the answer. but i  check angualr 7 application its not shadowed dom element. so raised this question.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular default view Encapsulation technique is `emulated`, which is provided by `encapsualation: viewEncapsulation.Emulated` , you don't have to explicitly define this. This emulate `Native` scoping of styles by adding an attribute containing surrogate id to the Host Element.

If you are using `encapsualation: viewEncapsulation.None`, this doesn't provide any template or style encapsulation, whatever the styles you define, will be applied globally.

If you are using `encapsualation: viewEncapsulation.Native` this will use the native Shadow DOM technique, but all the modern browsers does not support this.

Comment: Thanks for answer. but i am looking how viewEncapsulation works internally.